# how to install tensorflow 0.9 or 1.0.0 in 2018?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, windows-10

Hy, im sorry if this question has already been asked, please point me to right direction, i've been searching for the solution. There is a project that i want to run and it needs tensorflow earlier version. I have read other questions as well but i can't find a good answer on how to get tensorflow 0.9 or 1.0.0? please help.
My windows version is 10 and
python 3.6.4 anaconda custom 64 bit

Comment: You can access old releases from the [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases?after=v1.2.0-rc1). It also seems like 1.0 is available in conda repos.

Comment: 1.0 is there, but im not sure how to install it. its zip file is available there

Answer (score 1):

I would create a [virtual environment for this using `conda create`](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html), and then install the required version of TensorFlow in that environment. With `conda create` you can do this in a single line! Create your environment with:

```
conda create --name tf100 python=3.4 tensorflow=1.0.0
```

Virtual environments basically allow you to have conflicting versions of tools installed, compartmentalizing them so that your system is only aware of the ones that are "in" the environment on which you are working.

Now, when you are ready to work on your old version of tensorflow, you just type `activate tf100` in your command line. Then you just work as you usually would from there. To deactivate the environment (get back to your usual tensorflow setup), type `deactivate` in the command line.

If you need other packages to go along with tensorflow 1.0.0, you can install them using [`conda install`](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages) or `pip install` from the command line after activating your environment.

Comment: i tried that, but im still getting an error
" conda create -n tf100 tensorflow=1.0.0
Fetching package metadata .............

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - tensorflow 1.0.0*

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch"

Comment: There is no TF 1.0 for Windows 10 Python 3.6. You would need to downgrade your Python version (3.5 might suffice).

Comment: Updated my answer according to @xdurch0 's suggestion. You can also specify a different version of Python for your virtual environment.